# getattr to sort or pop from string

Tags: python, string, getattr

I'm a bit confused about using `getattr()` with a string. I can do something like

```
list_ = []
getattr(list_, 'insert')(0,1)
```

And that will work as expected. When I try to do `getattr(list_, 'sort')` or `getattr(list_, 'pop')` then it does not work as expected and will not modify the list. Why do only some string methods work with `getattr()`?

Comment: The functions such as `sort` do not take any arguments, but you need to call it: `getattr(list_, 'sort')()`, `getattr(list_, 'pop')()`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to call the function that `getattr()` returns:

```
>>> a = [2,3,1]
>>> getattr(a, 'sort')()
>>> a
[1, 2, 3]
>>> getattr(a, 'pop')()
3
>>> a
[1, 2]
```

Comment: Ahh, I had a misunderstanding of `getattr()`. It returns the function, so without the `()` at the end, I'm returning the function object without actually performing it. Thank you, I understand now.